# form action attribute Value in php

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to get a form's action attribute in server side php. 
I tried getting it through $_POST['action'] and $_REQUEST['action'] but this value is not set.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `action` attribute is not sent via a form submission.

Answer (score 0):

Check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` instead.